# Como fazer determinadas palavras dentro de uma div editavel fique de uma cor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, div

Eu tenho uma `DIV` que é editavel pelo usuario, só que eu queria que quando ee escrevece `Brasil` ele ficace somente esta palavra verde tabem como `EUA` ficase vermelho, mas somente palavras determinadas.

Codigo da DIV:

```
<div id="texto" contenteditable = "true" ></ div>
```

Comment: Como o usuário edita a div? O texto é carregado dentro de uma caixa de texto e depois salva por um botão?

Comment: Teria como colocar o código que você esta utilizando?

Comment: Você pode criar uma class CSS e quando for brasil chama a class .verde se for estados unidos a class .vermelho

Comment: @ViníciusBastos não é salva ainda, e ele acaba editando pela tag contenteditable = "true"

Comment: @DanielSaraiva como assim podia dar + detalhes ou ate um exemplo?

Comment: @Daniel, não encontrei como dar um evento change utilizando este atributo. (o máximo que encontrei foi isso [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ch6yn/) ). Posso ajudar em uma função para converter o texto, mas não sei quando esta função poderia ser chamada porque não conheço eventos para esta propriedade (se existem).

Comment: @Daniel execute o codigo abaixo e veja se entende

Comment: Em tempo, não é necessário atribuir o valor `true` à propriedade. Apenas a ocorrência de `contentEditable` já habilita a edição no elemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar o evento de keyup e pesquisar no texto se existe uma ocorrência da palavra, existindo esta palavra no texto basta substitui-la  fazendo um replace, como o próprio nome diz, e adicionar alguma tag para incluir o seu estilo.

Você pode melhora-la de várias formas, mas de base você poderia realizar algo como:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="text" contenteditable="true">O </ div>
```

**JS:**

```
var text = document.getElementById('text');


text.onkeyup = function(evt) {
    var counter = this.textContent.split(/(Brasil)/i).length;

  if (counter > 1 && (!this.lastCount || this.lastCount < counter) ) {
        this.lastCount = counter;
    this.innerHTML = this.textContent.replace(/(Brasil)/g, "<b class='green'>Brasil</b>&nbsp;");

        var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var lastNode = text.childNodes.item(text.childNodes.length -1)
    range.setStart(lastNode, 1);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
};
```

**CSS:**

```
.green{
  color:green;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/dcxLwsyc/)

Answer (score 1):

Como mencionei no comentário, não sei qual evento você usaria para chamar a função. Mas encontrando, uma opção é: ao salvar o texto, use o replace com expressão regular para inserir elementos span em volta das palavras, com os styles correspondentes.

```
var palavrasCores = {Brasil: "green", EUA: "red"};
var resultado = textoObtido.replace(/Brasil|EUA/gi, function(palavra){
    return '<span style="color: ' + palavrasCores[palavra] + '">' + palavra + '</span>';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkKey() {
var plaintext = document.getElementById("textbox");
if(plaintext.value == 'EUA') {
      plaintext.style.color = "#FF0000";
}
if(plaintext.value == 'BRASIL') {
      plaintext.style.color = "#66CD00";
   }
   if(plaintext.value != 'EUA' && plaintext.value != 'BRASIL') {
      plaintext.style.color = "#000000";
   }
}
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox" name="plaintext" onKeyUp="checkKey()">
```